# Are Azure Smart Lockout features now available for B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to determine if Azure Smart Lockout features are now available for B2C as of today?  I've found older documents discussing it, but I'm unable to find any official word if it is now available.  In the B2C tenant, under AD, Authentication methods is showing and you can open it up.  However, it says its in Preview and everything greyed out.   Does this mean that it will be available in B2C soon to be able to control lockout parameters?  [Azure Smart Lockout documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout) states that Smart Lockout will require minimum of AD Basic or high account to function.  Does anyone know if the B2C tenant will require its own lic or will a lic in the base subscription cover it?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Azure AD smart lockout being available for the local accounts in an Azure AD B2C tenant, then currently this isn't available.

Also note, the Azure AD Basic and Premium licenses aren't applicable to an Azure AD B2C tenant (in fact, the "Licenses" menu should be disabled).

Comment: Is there a way to configure smart lockout on B2C tenant, so that an administrator can manually unblock an account or at least provide more precise information to customers how long the lock out will last.

I have configured the 'Lockout duration in seconds' property to be a couple of seconds, however the account is still locked after this period passes.

Is the number of failed attempts restarted after a successful login? (e.g. when lockout threshold is 10, fail 6 times, succeed, fail 5 times, will the account be locked)

Answer (score 0):

Similar functionality to "smart lockout" **is available** in a B2C tenant, but isn't (yet) customisable.

Screenshot below of testing getting locked out after entering the password incorrectly 10 times (the default setting).

[image: Azure AD B2C Account is locked message]

According to Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-threat-management)

> Azure AD B2C uses a sophisticated strategy to lock accounts. The accounts are locked based on the IP of the request and the passwords entered. The duration of the lockout also increases based on the likelihood that it's an attack. After a password is tried 10 times unsuccessfully, a one-minute lockout occurs.

[cut]

> Currently, you can't:
>
> - Trigger a lockout with fewer than 10 failed logins
> - Retrieve a list of locked out accounts
> - **Configure the lock out policy**

Answer (score 0):

Azure Smart Lockout features are available for B2C. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management) article for details.
I wasn't able to save those values for some of my B2C tenants from Azure portal, but i was able to change Lockout threshold and lockout duration using Graph API using instructions from [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33679#issuecomment-504247947) post.